# how to allow EditText to expand pushing peer controls away

Tags: android, layout

The xml pasted below is the discussion page on an app I am writing.  It works much like a typical SMS messaging app displaying a message thread, a message entry edittext, and a send button.  The actual thread caption boxes are added to the LinearLayout named messageScroll in code.

It all works very well except when the message gets to be more than two lines, the EditText named etMessage squashes the btnSend button below it down to a barely visible thin line.  What I want to do is have etMessage push the ScrollView above it up.  I'll probably max etMessage to around 10 lines.

I have played with layout gravity and weight with no usable results.  If I give the button or the etMessage a weight, they expand way too tall initially.

How can I get the desired results?
Thanks, Dean

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvLocate"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Talk"
            style="@style/bigtype" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="User Name"
            style="@style/largetype"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" /> 
    </LinearLayout>     
    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroller"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".90"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_height="0dip">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/messageScroll"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"    
            android:orientation="vertical" >   
        </LinearLayout>     
    </ScrollView>

   <EditText 
       android:id="@+id/etMessage" 
       android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
       android:maxLength="160"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
       android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" />

    <Button
       android:id="@+id/btnSend"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="0dp"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dip"  
       android:onClick="btnSend_Clicked" 
       android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:layout_weight=".1"
       android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
       android:text="Send" />   

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have corrected the layout. Things to note are using proper layout params and integer values for layout_weights.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:focusable="true"
              android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
              android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        >
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvLocate"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Talk"
                 />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="User Name"

                android:layout_marginLeft="30dip" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scroller"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:layout_height="0dip">

        <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/messageScroll"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:gravity="bottom"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etMessage"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="160"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine" 
            android:text="afkajfjsajf asj ajfkjaldflkasdlkf aljfjl alkdfjkja aljfdkj alkdjflajlklfjkadlfjakd alkdfjlsjf "/>

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:onClick="btnSend_Clicked"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Vasudev.  That worked!  I was able to retain my big type styles and it still works.  But I don't understand why.  The more weight a control is given is supposed to allow it to expand it space relative to other controls.  You gave my ScrollView the highest weight yet my EditText now encroaches upon the ScrollView's space - which is the desired result.  Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: Here ScrollView is the only view that has the weight property. So whatever space is left after other view are laid out well go to scrollView. If there was another view with weight say 2, then the space would have been divided amongst them in their weight ratios i.e. second view getting twice the space of ScrollView.